# Align subscripts in math mode

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

Is there an easy way (maybe provided by `mathtools` that aligns normal subscripts)?

I know that I can do this manually with `\vphantom`, but I was looking for a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent Looks pretty bad:
\[
    T_\theta T_\theta^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
        \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
\]
adjustlimits doesn't work:
\[
    \adjustlimits T_\theta T_\theta^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
        \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
\]
vphantom does work
\[
    T_\theta^{\vphantom{-1}} T_\theta^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
        \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `^{} `?

Comment: @daleif Sorry, at first I didn't understand that you intended `^{}` instead of `^{\vphantom{-1}}`. However, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `\mathstrut`, which is exactly a `\vphantom(`, and always put subscripts within `{}`.

*Edit:* The Master says that `\vphantom{-}` is conceptually better, I've created a new command for convenience:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\egreg}{\vphantom{-}}% new command for alignment adjustment (you can choose another name, of course!) 
\begin{document}
    \noindent egreg's version: 
    \[
    T_{\theta}^{\egreg}\, T_{\theta}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] % I've added also a little space \,
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
    -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
    \]
    \noindent My previous version: 
    \[
    T_{\theta}^{\mathstrut}\, T_{\theta}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] % I've added also a little space \,
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
    -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vphantom{-}` would be conceptually better; the minus sign has a depth (equal to `+`) and is responsible for the fact that `^{}` is not enough, which it would be for `T_{\theta}^{}T_{\theta}^{2}`

Comment: @egreg I've added your version, please let me know if I acted correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Another manual workaround is to separate subscripts from superscripts by using braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \noindent 
    \[
        T_{\theta}\, {T_{\theta}}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] % I've also added also a little space \,
        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
        \sin\theta & \cos\theta
        \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
        \end{pmatrix*}
        = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
    \]
\end{document}
```

In the final output, the subscripts are aligned. The result is slightly different from the first solution:

[image: Example Result]

Comment: If you go this route, it would probably be a good idea to also (a) snug up the `\theta` subscript to the letter `T`, say, `T_{\!\theta}`, and (b) to snug up the superscript `-1` to the material that precedes it, say, `{...}`{\!-1}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the fontdimens accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    % Regular subscript positon
    \fontdimen16\textfont2=\dimexpr
        \fontdimen17\textfont2 % subscript position in presence of superscript
      + \fontdimen19\textfont2 % subscript drop in presence of superscript
    \relax
    T_\theta T_\theta^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
        \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
        \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
        -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{pmatrix*}
    = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = I
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot, the two "`\theta`" subscripts aren't at the same depth. Is this intentional?