# Specific alignment of subscripts in math mode joint with overleftarrow. How to avoid phantom space fiddling?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, subscripts, stackengine, phantom

The `oveleft/rightarrow`-command is not optimal because it shiftes indices to much to the right in formulas like:

```
$\overleftarrow{D}_v$
```

Therefore, I use the following macro which I have adapted from some answer on this site a while ago. (Sorry, I cannot give credit to the author of the code because I forgot where I read it.)

```
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\overleftarrow{\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
```

The command

```
$\constantoverleftarrow{D_v}$
```

then gives the desired result. So far so good. Now, I want to align the subscripts as in the follwing code:

```
$\constantoverleftarrow{D_{v'\vphantom{\scalebox{0.73}{$\int$}}}}x_{v,v'}^d$
```

If you use

```
$\constantoverleftarrow{D_{v'}}x_{v,v'}^d$
```

instead, you will see that the `v`'s and the `v'`'s in the subscripts are not properly aligned. With the naked eye, I chose the value `0.73` in the `scalebox` to more or less achieve what I want.

Can someone please tell me how I do this properly? I hardly want to choose for each formula a value in the `scalebox`, as you can imagine. Because this takes incredibly much time. Also, I want the alignement to be perfect and not only approximative. How can I achieve this?

I tried several things now and was not able to do it. There are many questions like this on the site. But I was not able to find a solution. Note, I want the arrow over the `D` not shifted upwards or anything like this.

**Related.**

[165499](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165499/vphantom-and-superscripts), [174122](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174122/can-i-move-the-hat-symbol-vertically-upwards), [354871](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354871/align-subscripts-in-math-mode).

**MWE.**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\overleftarrow{\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\[
\constantoverleftarrow{D_{v'}}x_{v,v'}^d
\]
\end{document}
```

This MWE repdocues indeed the error. You see, the indices are not aligned. Only if you add the integral. The problem is caused by the `d` in the superscript as I noticed now while playing around. I am sorry that I forgot the `d` in my initial post.

**Possible solution for the right result.**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\overleftarrow{\hphantom{D}\vphantom{D}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand{\nhphantom}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\hspace{-\the\wd0}}
\begin{document}
%This is not perfect because the space between $D$ and the subscript $v'$ is not exactly like in $D_{v'}$ but almost and slightly smaller. The indices are however aligned. The best I can do.
\[
\constantoverleftarrow{D\nhphantom{$\displaystyle x_{}^{}$}\phantom{x}_{\vphantom{,}v'}^{\vphantom{d}}}x_{v,v'}^d
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a little difficult to make out what you're asking. Could you turn your code fragments into a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156366)? It should start with `\documentclass`, and end with `\end{document}` and should load the minimum number of packages that you need to illustrate the problem. (And it should compile.)

Comment: Yes, I should do this later because in the pictures below it looks great but in my file the results are not ok. @Circumscribe

Comment: Ah, I see. The different depths of the subscript is due to the presence of a superscript (the `^d`). I believe the `supdepth` package "fixes" this. (See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10309/156366).)

Comment: `subdepth` with option `low-sup` does the job. Strangely enough, it only work inbetween `\[...\]` but not inbetween `$...$`.

Comment: The `low-sup` option is buggy, I think it doesn't work in inline equations with superscript that stick out below the baseline. The only fix I know involves redefining `^`, and I'm not sure I should be recommending that since it is a rather drastic thing to do. I don't really know how the package works though, so there might very well be better ways to fix that problem.

Comment: Actually, I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89404/156366) may be the problem there.

Comment: For me, the problem is solved now anyway, because I use a way without the `subdepth` package similar but not the same (the same does not work properly) as posted in my question under *possible solution*. Thank you very much, anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an MWE has not been provided, it is not exactly clear what the issue is.  But here is a stab...at something.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\cola#1\endcola}
\def\cola#1#2\endcola{\stackengine{0pt}{}{$\overleftarrow{#1}$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
  \phantom{#1}#2}
\begin{document}
$\overleftarrow{D}_v$

$\constantoverleftarrow{D_v}$

$\constantoverleftarrow{D_{v'}}x_{v,v'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @John Kormylo and @Seven B. Segletes Thank you a lot! I appreciate your help! This is really great. I think you understood the issue very well. I can see that is working. But I don't understand why. Where do you set the horizontal length of the arrow to be equal to `D`? I ask so that I can modify in other formulas in case I need it.

Comment: @user66288 The `$\overleftarrow{#1}$` is what typesets the overarrowed `D`, since `#1` is the first token of your argument.  Later in the definition, the `\phantom{#1}` skips by the width of a `D`, so that the subscript can be set as if were next to the plain letter.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\oveleftarrow` is centered while subscripts and superscripts are not.

Note that this is math style dependent.  That can be fixed with a lot more effort.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348566/how-to-create-special-math-macros-which-preserve-the-current-style).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\combine}[3]% #1=centered preop, #2=operand, #3=postop
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{$#1{\phantom{#2}}$}%
  \sbox1{$#2$}%
  \usebox0\hspace{-0.5\wd0}\hspace{-0.5\wd1}\usebox1\hspace{-\wd1}\phantom{#2}#3
\egroup}

\begin{document}
$\overleftarrow{D} D_v \combine{\overleftarrow}{D}{_v}$

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using smaller arrows (like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248297/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overleftsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overleftrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftrightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip0.4pt}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\overrightsmallarrow{D}_v$ $\overleftsmallarrow{D}_v$ $\overleftrightsmallarrow{D}_v$

$D_v$ $D_v$ $D_v$
\end{document}
```

[image]